# transfer value to active cell using vba

Tags: vba

I want the value of "Learner" to be placed in the Active Cell

This code gives me an error:

```
Sheets("Data").Range(ActiveCell).Value _
        = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Learner").Value
```

Why doesn't ActiveCell work here?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Learner").Value`

The active cell can only be a single cell at any one time, and so you don't need to qualify it with a sheet or a range argument. Also, `ActiveCell` is a range object, so you don't need to use the `Range()` method to address it.